# Getting Error after reading xlsx file in R

Tags: java, r

I am trying to import a excel file into R. I have installed java 64bit as well as JAVA_HOME even i have tried but not worked and this error is shown while trying to load the file.

Please help me to find the solution of this error.

```
> cameraData <- read.xlsx("D:/R/Practise/Baltimore Speed Cameras/Excel/cameras.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, header = TRUE)
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
```

Comment: Maybe that path causes problem? You can try to check it's correctness with other, simpler R scirpt.

Comment: You could try `readxl` as that doesn't require Java. Best ...

Comment: @I.G., what to you makes this script not simple? While using the java-dependent `read.xlsx` has caused me many problems (therefore I agree with p0bs' suggestion), I don't know how much simpler this code can be. (BTW: spaces in directories generally work fine in R, though there are times when it is problematic on Windows. I have not found this to be one of those problematic situations.)